# Laptop screen turns off when unplugged

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, hibernate

I have windows 10 on my laptop and I have had windows 10 on my laptop for 4 years now. recently, my laptop screen randomly turns of after about 2-5 minutes when not plugged in (power cord), however, the laptop is on and the light on the on/off button is also on. To bring the screen back on, I have to turn off the laptop by pressing the on/off button, after which the battery is drained down to 7-10%.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: It's hard to understand from your description, but it sounds like your battery id dead. My opinion is based on what I believe you said here: "To bring the screen back on, I have to turn off the laptop by pressing the on/off button, after which the battery is drained down to 7-10%." I assume that the battery drains very quickly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - wasn't sure of best way of explaining the situation. When the battery is drained to 7-10%, I can use the laptop with plugging in the charger until the battery completely runs out - does this still mean the battery is dead - this only started happening recently like a month ago and I did research but couldn't find anything and decided to post here.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same thing happened to me. It's your battery that's gone off, although four years seems a bit early (but not unheard of).

The only solution is purchasing of a new battery.

P.S. Thanks to @[Xavierjazz](https://superuser.com/users/11546/xavierjazz) for the clarification

Comment: Hi, thanks for the respond. As said, when the battery goes to 7-10% after i turn off and on the laptop I am able to use it without the screen going of until the battery completely dies so i assumed that the battery isn't dead because it lasts for about 10-15 minutes at 7-10%.

Comment: I don't mean *completely* dead, but it's obviously nearing the end of its usable life, so the charge goes down over time. 

I'm only speculating, but some manufacturers actively use planned obsolescence for their benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Your battery is failing. Replace it.